# How do I make this number guessing game restart once you guess the number right?

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't figure out how to make the game restart itself. I think I need to put something where it says System.out.println("Ok, let's play again."); 
What do I need to put there to restart it? What am I missing?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessMyNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random Bob = new Random();
        int NumToGuess = Bob.nextInt(20);
        int NumOfTries = 0;
        Scanner Bill = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        boolean win = false;

        while (win == false) {

            System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20, can you guess it?");
            guess = Bill.nextInt();
            NumOfTries++;

            if (guess == NumToGuess) {
                win = true;
            }
            else if (guess < NumToGuess) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
            }
            else if (guess > NumToGuess) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Congratulations!");
        System.out.println("The number was " + NumToGuess);
        System.out.println("It took you " + NumOfTries + " tries"); 

        while (win == true) {
            String YesOrNo;
            YesOrNo = Bill.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? " + YesOrNo);
            YesOrNo = Bill.nextLine();

            if (YesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                System.out.println("Ok, let's play again.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Ok, maybe next time.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're missing that you stay in a loop for all eternity rather than go back to the beginning of the program flow.

Comment: @crpittman18 By the way, ```Bob.nextInt(20)``` generates a number between 0 (inclusive) and 20 (exclusive).

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this too:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random bob = new Random();
    Scanner bill = new Scanner(System.in);

    String yesOrNo = "";
    do {

        int numToGuess = bob.nextInt(20);
        int numOfTries = 0;
        int guess = 0;
        boolean win = false;

        while (win == false) {

            System.out
                    .println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20, can you guess it?");
            guess = Bill.nextInt();
            numOfTries++;

            if (guess == numToGuess) {
                win = true;
            } else if (guess < numToGuess) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
            } else if (guess > numToGuess) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Congratulations!");
        System.out.println("The number was " + NumToGuess);
        System.out.println("It took you " + NumOfTries + " tries");

        yesOrNo = bill.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? " + yesOrNo);
        yesOrNo = bill.nextLine();

    } while (yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

    System.out.println("Ok, maybe next time.");
    System.exit(0);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is the problem.  You likely copied the first loop.  In the second loop you set `YesOrNo` not `win`.  So it will loop forever.

```
   while (win == true) {          //You test win
        String YesOrNo;
        YesOrNo = Bill.nextLine() //You set YesOrNo
        ...
   }                              //You never set win to anything new so it loops forever
```

Typical way to solve the restart problem is to use one loop not two and have the user enter -1 when they want to quit.  That way the game keeps going win or lose until they are done.

By the way, we use camelCase in java so `YesOrNo` should be `yesOrNo` but that's just a style issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the whole method body into a `while` loop that checks if a flag (e.g. `boolean continueGame`) is `true`. I mean something like this:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessMyNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random Bob = new Random();
        Scanner Bill = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        boolean continueGame = true; // the flag (boolean) that allows us to check if the user wants to continue the game or not

        while(continueGame) {
            boolean win = false;
            int NumToGuess = Bob.nextInt(20); // moved into the while loop because they need to be initialized every time you start the game
            int NumOfTries = 0;

            while (win == false) {

                System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 20, can you guess it?");
                guess = Bill.nextInt();
                NumOfTries++;

                if (guess == NumToGuess) {
                    win = true;
                }
                else if (guess < NumToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
                }
                else if (guess > NumToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Congratulations!");
            System.out.println("The number was " + NumToGuess);
            System.out.println("It took you " + NumOfTries + " tries"); 

            // As CandiedOrange already noted, you need to remove the while loop which was here.
            String YesOrNo;
            YesOrNo = Bill.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? " + YesOrNo);
            YesOrNo = Bill.nextLine();

            if (YesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                System.out.println("Ok, let's play again.");
                continueGame = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Ok, maybe next time.");
                continueGame = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's about it. If you have a question about this answer, feel free to ask.

Comment: I did everything you said and it loops now, but it keeps the same number and doesn't switch to a new one when you continue the game after you won.

Comment: @crpittman18 Yeah, I'm sorry. I forgot to put ```NumToGuess``` and ```NumOfTries``` into the loop that I created. The code in the post should be working now.

Comment: @crpittman18 You're welcome. But don't forget to vote CannotCode's answer up as well, since he got almost the same as me.

Comment: @crpittman18 By the way, the most common way of saying thanks here is accepting an answer (ticking the check mark). If you think the answer was useful, you can up-vote it as well (clicking the arrow up). :) HINT: You also get reputation by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use labelled BREAK statement. 
Or you need to re - run the program as your while loops ends and you are out.